# Prevent a link from loading the clicked link in the modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list of links which when clicked should open a modal window with some information. I am using `e.preventDefault();` to prevent the default action of the browser and then add my own custom code to load my own data in the modal. The content loads just fine but after a few seconds the whole website whose link I clicked get loaded inside the modal.

1. It only happens with links from a specific website.
2. The links from that website should be the first one that I click. Clicking on other links first resolves this issue.

Here is my code:

```
$('a.modal-link').on('click', openModal);

function openModal(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  var link = $(this).attr("href");
  var text = $(this).text();
  safeModal(link, text);
};

function safeModal(linkUrl, linkText) {
  var link = linkUrl;
  var page = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
  var text = linkText;
  var ajaxURL = "http://example.com/script.php";

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST"
    , url: ajaxURL
    , data: {
        link: link
        , page: page
    }
    , success: function (markup) {
        $(".feed-modal .modal-body").html(markup);
    }
  })
};
```

I can also provide the link to the actual website, so you can see the issue yourself (I may not have explained it properly).

UPDATE: I am adding [the link](http://freadio.com/android/). Try clicking on the first headline and you will see the issue. After that, reload the webpage and then click on the sixth link. Now, close the modal and click on the first link again. Everything should work perfectly this time.

UPDATE: The syntax error doesn't exist. I made it in the question by mistake. :)

Comment: First of all, try to get rid off js errors. Uncaught ReferenceError: swfobject is not defined. It could stop propagation of you script

Comment: @RafałŁyczkowski The error is because of the other domain. It has nothing to do with my code.

Answer (score 0):

This code has a syntax error (delete `})`):

```
success: function (markup) {
  $(".feed-modal .modal-body").html(markup);
  }) //delete this
}
```

The whole function should be:

```
function safeModal(linkUrl, linkText) {
  var link = linkUrl;
  var page = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
  var text = linkText;
  var ajaxURL = "http://example.com/script.php";

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST"
    , url: ajaxURL
    , data: {
        link: link
        , page: page
    }
    , success: function (markup) {
        $(".feed-modal .modal-body").html(markup);
        //}) without this
    }
  })
};
```

Working [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/paolobasso99/py32acvL/)